# Problem mapping over data from API as its just an object not an array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have this data structure coming from an api:

```
{
  "value": 0,
  "time": [
    "2021-10-15"
  ],
  "innerArray": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "Value": [
        0
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to access the element by:

```
let dataLoop = data // object from api
```

then I am doing:

```
   function Loop() {
        dataLoop.map((inner: any) => {
            console.log('series =', inner.innerArray);
        })
    };
```

But I am getting `TypeError: dataLoop.map is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because

```
{
  "value": 0,
  "time": [
    "2021-10-15"
  ],
  "innerArray": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "Value": [
        0
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

is an object, you can map only on `Array` type elements.

`innerArray` is an element on which you can `.map` like this:

```
    dataLoop.innerArray.map((inner: any) => {
        console.log('series =', inner);
    })
```

to be able to map through an object you have to use [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) like:

```
Object.entries(data).map(([key,value])=>{
  console.log(key,value)
})
```

for example, so output would be like :

[image]

Comment: Ok but how to access that?

Comment: @Sole do you want to map over whole object or `innerArray`?  Which data do you need?

Comment: `innerArray` but be good to knwo how to map all data

Comment: @Sole I updated answer

Comment: Ok how to access just the innerArray?

Comment: @Sole read answer again I put it there also

Comment: @Sole if my answer helped you out please sign it as a solution, thanks :)

Comment: Hi Sowam, I have marked as the answer - thanks